# Variety of Quiver Representations

Tags: representation-theory, quiver

I have been reading chapter 8 of Ralf Schiffler's 'Quiver Representations', where he proves Gabriel's Theorem characterizing connected quivers with finitely many isoclasses of indecomposable representations. There he has defined, for a finite quiver $Q=(Q_0,Q_1)$ without oriented cycles and for a (fixed) dimension vector $\textbf{d}:= (d_i)_{i \in Q_0} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}^n$, the space $E_\textbf{d}$ of representations $M$ of $Q$ having dimension vector equal to $\textbf{d}$, and the group $G_\textbf{d} := \prod_{i \in Q_0} GL_{d_i} (k)$, which acts on $E_\textbf{d}$ by conjugation: that is, for $g:=(g_i)_{i \in Q_0} \in G_\textbf{d}$ and $M := (M_i, \phi_\alpha)_{i \in Q_0, \alpha \in Q_1} \in E_\textbf{d}$, 
$$g \cdot M := (M_i, \hspace{1mm} g_{t(\alpha)} \hspace{0.5mm} \phi_\alpha \hspace{0.5mm} g_{s(\alpha)}^{-1})_{i \in Q_0, \alpha \in Q_1} \in E_\textbf{d}$$
where the source and target of arrow $\alpha \in Q_1$ are given by $s(\alpha)$ and $t(\alpha)$ respectively.

For a representation $M \in E_\textbf{d}$, we denote the orbit of $M$ under the above action by $\mathcal{O}_M$.

In Lemma 8.2, he views $\mathcal{O}_M, G_\textbf{d}$ and $Aut(M)$ as varieties, and gives a relation between their dimensions (as varieties), which arises essentially out of the standard bijection used to prove the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem in elementary group theory. Unfortunately, the only definition of an algebraic variety that I am familiar with is that it is the set of common zeroes of a system of polynomial equations over the real or complex numbers. It is not clear to me how $\mathcal{O}_M, G_\textbf{d}$ and $Aut(M)$ may be viewed as varieties in this definition (or if there is an equivalent definition in which things are clearer), and I would really appreciate some help regarding the same.

Comment: $\operatorname{GL}_n(k)$ can be viewed as a variety by taking the open set in $k^{n \times n}$ consisting of points where the determinant does not vanish. For instance, $\operatorname{GL}_2(k)$ is the open set in $k^4$ defined by $wx - yz \neq 0$. By taking products, we get $G_{\mathbf{d}}$ as an algebraic variety.

Comment: $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ can be viewed as a variety in much the same way. You have some linear space (all $Q_0$-graded $k$-linear maps $M \to M$) and you want them to be invertible (this is the same determinant nonvanishing condition) and you want them to satisfy some polynomial conditions in terms of the maps $\phi_a$. So you get $\operatorname{Aut}(M)$ as an algebraic variety in much the same way.

Comment: The difficult one by far is the orbits $\mathcal{O}_M$, and in the quiver representation world it is common to either take something called the _categorical quotient_, where the points of $\mathcal{O}_M$ are in bijection with the _closed_ orbits of $\operatorname{Rep}_k (Q, \mathbf{d})$ under $G_{\mathbf{d}}$, or the _GIT quotient_ which depends on some stability condition and a whole bunch of theory.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Based on your answers for $GL_n(k)$ and $Aut(M)$, I suppose then we could provide the following structure of a variety on $\mathcal{O}_M$: we first observe that $\mathcal{O}_M = \{ M' \in Rep(Q) | M' \cong M \}$, so each element of $\mathcal{O}_M$ is uniquely characterized by the tuple $(\phi_\alpha)_{\alpha \in Q_1}$. For any two elements $M$ and $M'$ belonging to the same orbit, their corresponding tuples $(\phi_\alpha)_{\alpha \in Q_1}$ and $(\phi'_\alpha)_{\alpha \in Q_1}$ must satisfy a polynomial-type relation.

Comment: (Continued from above) So we take all of the aforementioned relations together with the ones for nonzero determinant and the set $\mathcal{O}_M$ becomes a variety in this manner. Does this work?

Comment: I think I misunderstood - if all we care about are single orbits (and not putting them together into some "quotient space"), things are easier. An algebraic group $G$ acting on a variety $X$ is a map $a \colon G \times X \to X$. The _orbit_ of $x \in X$ is the set of points $G \cdot x := \operatorname{image}(a(-, x)) \subseteq X$. It can be shown (consult any book on linear algebraic groups) that the orbit sets $G\cdot x$ is "locally closed" (open in a closed subset of X) and hence may be equipped with a canonical variety structure inherited from $X$.